# SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bigint (Laravel Herokuapp Postgresql)

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

im trying figure out  with this problem, already search on every website getting same error, not work at all,.,

here is my simple code hope u guys understand

> migration diagnosa

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('diagnosas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
        $table->double('hasil_nilai');
        $table->date('diagnosa_date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

> migration diagnosa_gejala

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('diagnosa_gejalas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('diagnosa_gejala_id');
    $table->foreign('diagnosa_gejala_id')->references('id')->on('diagnosas')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('gejala_id');
        $table->foreign('gejala_id')->references('id')->on('gejalas');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

> migration dianosa_kerusakan

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('diagnosa_kerusakans', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('diagnosa_kerusakan_id');
        $table->foreign('diagnosa_kerusakan_id')->references('id')->on('diagnosas')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('kerusakan_id');
        $table->foreign('kerusakan_id')->references('id')->on('kerusakans');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

> model diagnosa

```
public function user_id() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function diagnosaGejala()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DiagnosaGejala::class);
}

public function diagnosaKerusakan()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DiagnosaKerusakan::class);
}
```

> model diagnosa gejala

```
public function diagnosa_gejala_id() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Diagnosa::class, 'diagnosa_gejala_id');
}

public function gejala_id() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Gejala::class, 'gejala_id');
}
```

}

> model diagnosa kerusakan

```
public function diagnosa_kerusakan_id() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Diagnosa::class, 'diagnosa_kerusakan_id');
}

public function kerusakan_id() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Kerusakan::class, 'kerusakan_id');
}
```

here is little code controller post/save to database diagnosa, diagnosa_gejala, and diagnosa_kerusakan

```
$kerusakan = Kerusakan::where('kode_kerusakan', $getCode)->select('id')->get();

                $authUser = Auth::user()->id;

                $diagnosa = new Diagnosa;
                $diagnosa->user_id = $authUser;
                $diagnosa->hasil_nilai = $getValue * 100;
                $diagnosa->diagnosa_date = date('Y-m-d');
                $diagnosa->save();

                $diagnosaGejalaBody = [];
                foreach ($gejala as $key => $result) {
                    $diagnosaGejalaBody[$key]['diagnosa_gejala_id'] = $diagnosa->id;
                    $diagnosaGejalaBody[$key]['gejala_id'] = $result;
                }
                DiagnosaGejala::insert($diagnosaGejalaBody);

                $diagnosaKerusakanBody = [];
                foreach ($kerusakan as $key => $result) {
                    $diagnosaKerusakanBody[$key]['diagnosa_kerusakan_id'] = $diagnosa->id;
                    $diagnosaKerusakanBody[$key]['kerusakan_id'] = $result['id'];
                }
                DiagnosaKerusakan::insert($diagnosaKerusakanBody);

                return redirect('diagnosa-hasil/' . $diagnosa->id);
```

this is little code, controller trying to get data by parameter $id, for sending to blade with url "diagnosa-hasil/{id}"

```
$getId = Diagnosa::find($id);
        $diagnosa = Diagnosa::whereIn('diagnosas.id', $getId)
            ->join('diagnosa_gejalas', 'diagnosa_gejala_id', '=', 'diagnosas.id')
            ->join('diagnosa_kerusakans', 'diagnosa_kerusakan_id', '=', 'diagnosas.id')
            ->join('gejalas', 'gejala_id', '=', 'gejalas.id')
            ->join('kerusakans', 'kerusakan_id', '=', 'kerusakans.id')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```

this error from herokuapp

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "95.64" (SQL: select * from "diagnosas" inner join "diagnosa_gejalas" on "diagnosa_gejala_id" = "diagnosas"."id" inner join "gejalas" on "gejala_id" = "gejalas"."id" inner join "diagnosa_kerusakans" on "diagnosa_kerusakan_id" = "diagnosas"."id" inner join "kerusakans" on "kerusakan_id" = "kerusakans"."id" where "diagnosas"."id" in (1, 1, 95.64, 2021-11-18, 2021-11-18T07:02:43.000000Z, 2021-11-18T07:02:43.000000Z))
```

on my localhost:8000 is work fine,.,

Comment: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "96.25" (SQL: select * from "diagnosas" inner join "diagnosa_gejalas" on "diagnosa_gejala_id" = "diagnosas"."id" inner join "gejalas" on "gejala_id" = "gejalas"."id" inner join "diagnosa_kerusakans" on "diagnosa_kerusakan_id" = "diagnosas"."id" inner join "kerusakans" on "kerusakan_id" = "kerusakans"."id" where "diagnosas"."id" in (3, 1, 96.25, 2021-11-18, 2021-11-18T10:42:13.000000Z, 2021-11-18T10:42:13.000000Z))

and this is snippet code error from herokuapp.com

Comment: please share code not images

Comment: @OMR already sir, sorry for my bad english, hope u undestand sir, what im trying explain